# Creating loop using Rvest to scrape text into dataframe from multiple urls

Tags: function, for-loop, url, rvest

I'm having trouble creating a loop that will scrape text from a list of urls using rvest. I can scape text for a single url, but calling multiple urls through a loop isn't working for me. I've scoured past posts and haven't been able to make any solutions work. Any guidance is much appreciated. Here's an example of a url I'm trying to pull text from, it's the "last sold, date, and price" line below the photo: https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1501-Rollins-Dr-90063/home/6954819

**I've tried using a function...**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
urls <- read_csv('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\URLFile.csv',show_col_types = FALSE)
lst <- lapply(urls, function(x) {
    pg <- read_html(x)
    html_nodes(pg, "div.ListingStatusBannerSection")
    html_text() 
})
```

**as well as a for-loop...**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
urls <- read_csv('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\URLFile.csv',show_col_types = FALSE)
for(i in length(urls)) {
   link = paste0(urls[i])
    page <- read_html(link[i]) %>%
    text %>%
    html_nodes(page[i], "div.ListingStatusBannerSection") %>%
    html_text() 
}
df <- data.frame(urls,webpage)
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's quite hard to know what is going on without at least a handful of the URLs. If you could run dput(head(urls)), and edit your question to add it to it, that would be great

Comment: Thank you, I updated the post with an example url

Answer (score 0):

`lapply(urls, function(x){...})` applies that function on every column of `urls` tibble while you probably want it to iterate over values in a single column. And there's no input for `html_text()` -- previous expression should be followed by a pipe:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

urls <- tribble(
  ~link,
  "https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1501-Rollins-Dr-90063/home/6954819",
  "https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1517-N-Eastern-Ave-90063/home/6955418"
)
urls
#> # A tibble: 2 × 1
#>   link                                                                       
#>   <chr>                                                                      
#> 1 https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1501-Rollins-Dr-90063/home/6954819   
#> 2 https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1517-N-Eastern-Ave-90063/home/6955418

lapply(urls$link, function(x) {
  read_html(x) %>%  html_nodes("div.ListingStatusBannerSection") %>% html_text() 
})
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "LAST SOLD ON SEP 22, 2023 FOR $590,000"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "SOLD ON JUL 21, 2023"
```

If this single element is all you need to collect, you don't need much more than just `rowwise()` and `mutate()`:

```r
urls %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(status = 
           read_html(link) %>% 
           html_nodes("div.ListingStatusBannerSection") %>% 
           html_text()) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   link                                                                    status
#>   <chr>                                                                   <chr> 
#> 1 https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1501-Rollins-Dr-90063/home/69548… LAST …
#> 2 https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1517-N-Eastern-Ave-90063/home/69… SOLD …
```

( presumably you do know that scraping goes against  https://www.redfin.com/about/terms-of-use )